# How to pass json data through websocket sampler in jmeter?

Tags: jmeter

How to pass json data through websocket sampler in jmeter?

As I am not able to do testing of websocket using jmeter.

Need Help regarding web socket. If any body have worked on this then please help me out.

please connect me on my email : honey.ushyaku@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

[JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) is a sub-type of plain text so just put your JSON payload into "Request data" input field:

[image]

In the above example I refer to [JMeter WebSocket Samplers by Peter Doornbosch](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/) plugin. The description from the author is very good and there is a number of [sample scripts](https://bitbucket.org/pjtr/jmeter-websocket-samplers/src/master/samples/) you can use as a reference

check out [JMeter WebSocket Samplers - A Practical Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-websocket-samplers-a-practical-guide)  article if you need comprehensive instructions.